# Would using industrial carbon dioxide emissions to grow plants or algae pose a threat to public health?

Tags: food-safety, toxicity

An idea that has been passed around lately as a way of hitting two major birds with one stone — carbon dioxide pollution from industrial activities and food shortages — is diverting carbon dioxide emissions from power plants and factories to greenhouses and algae farms to improve growth rate.

While certainly an intriguing idea to reduce pollution while simultaneously increasing crop yields, do toxic gases in industrial emissions pose a threat to public health by potentially making crops grown using this technology toxic, or is there some element of how plants process these gases that eliminates or at least greatly reduces such risk?

Note: Seeing as this question lives in the intersect of biology and health, I've cross-posted it [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/71163).

Comment: @LangLangC While I think this question is highly relevant in terms of public good and a decent reference for future readers, the reason it was asked so broadly is that I don't know enough about these pollutants to know which would pose the greatest risk, and if I did then I could research those rather than posing the question. If you have any suggestions for narrowing this in a way that doesn't detract from the potential usefulness of the question, please let me know.

Comment: @LangLangC That sounds like the beginning and middle of a really great answer

Comment: Please don't crosspost. It's not the pollutants, but as was pointed out on Biology, not knowing the implementation makes it broad and very hard to predict a health outcome.

Comment: This is done in Holland, and I think the question is off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about personal health.

Comment: @GrahamChiu, on the [what topics can I ask about](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page the very first bullet is "Environmental or nutritional factors that affect health" so I respectfully disagree

Comment: the question is redundant because the solution is practiced in forward thinking countries.

Comment: Or, ask on https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Interesting question, but it's borderline here and I have to agree it would be more appropriate in earthscience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to EarthScience.SE